# Disabled attr added to button before toggling input field after click

Tags: jquery, typescript, vue.js

I have an Add button that once clicked will toggle the visibility of an input field for the user to use. I want to disable the Add button once the user clicks on it and the input field appears.
Currently, when I applied the change to disable my Add button it seems like it is disabling it before the toggle kicks in and the input field is not showing up.

This is what i have:

```
button.btn(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#addNewField', @click='disableBtn($event)') Add

#addNewField.collapse
    input.form-control(type='text', v-model='inputValue'...)

disableBtn(event: Event) {
   let el = event.target as HTMLElement;
   el.querySelector("button");
   el.setAttribute("disabled", "");
}
```

How can I properly disable the button AFTER the toggle so the input field is showing?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using vue and typescript

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've updated the tags on your question so that it's more visible to people with those skillsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Vue, everything should be a state unless you know what you're doing.

What you are asking can be achieved with something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="add" :disabled="isAdding">
      Add
    </button>

    <input v-show="isAdding" v-model="inputValue" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isAdding: false,
      inputValue: "",
    }
  },

  methods: {
    add() {
      this.isAdding = true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I completely forgot about :disabled. I did try this implementation but unfortunately, the button is still disabling before showing the input field.

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox or jsfiddle of it?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. In the click method i handled the collapse toggle for the field before setting the button to disabled - so that part worked. I also added a ref to the button so i am only disabling that specific Add button since i have multiple Add buttons on the same page.